# How do I get notification for new mail in all folders in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, notification

I am using evolution mail client from my mapi account. Whenever a mail arrives in inbox I get notification but if the mail arrives in some other folder then I dont receive notification. How can I receive notification for all my folder. I am using 11.04

Answer (score 4):

Does this help?

[image: check in all folders]

1. In the "Edit" menu click "Preferences".
2. There click the mail account of your choice and press the "Edit" button. The account editor will pop up.
3. In the editor select the rider "Receiving Options".
4. There you may select the ceckboxes next to "Check for new messages in all folders" and/or "Check for new messages in subscribed folders".

Comment: It'd be a nice bonus if you could explain the picture as well, for the benefit of the blind and visually impaired. (not to mention Google!)